# Attribute is setting as NULL

Tags: lightning

I am trying to pass an attribute from Parent component to Child component. But in Child components JS, the value is changed to NULL.

From Parent component, calling the child component:

```
<c:childcomponent aura:id="filterPane" portalUserCountry="{!v.userInfo.country}">
```

Child Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="portalUserCountry" type="String" default="" access="public"/>

<div class="mdc-grid">
   Test Country {!v.portalUserCountry} <!-- this shows correct value -->
</div>
```

But in Child helper JS it shows NULL.

```
var portalUserCountry = component.get("v.portalUserCountry");  // This is null.
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: How is component defined in a controller/helper?

Comment: @kurunve 

In Controller:
`({
 init : function(component, event, helper) {
  helper.init(component);
 },
    filterCriteria:function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.filterCriteria(component);
    },

})`

In Helper:
`filterCriteria: function( component ){
         var portalUserCountry = component.get("v.portalUserCountry");  
         console.log('$$ portalUserCountry: ' + portalUserCountry);
}`